# react Native unable to hide a tab in the bottom bar using react-navigation

Tags: react-native, jsx

So I tried everything, however I am unable to make this tab disappear removing it

I tried:

```
tabBarOptions: { 
    visible: false
}
```

but without any success.

```
Menu: {
       screen: OtherStack,
       tabBarOptions: {
           visible: false
       },
       navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
           tabBarOnPress: () => {
               navigation.toggleMenuDrawer()
           },
       }),
     },
```

Comment: Do you want to hide the tab in some condition?

Answer (score 0):

please explain the details and  react-navigation version that you used.

if you use latest react-navigation which is version 5.x, then if you wanna hide specific bottom tab in specific screen, you can try this below code,
basically, you just pass `tabBarVisible: false,`.

```
import React from 'react'

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs'

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator()

export function tabNav() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      backBehavior="initialRoute">
      <Tab.Screen
        name="tabChat"
        component={ChatComponentExample} 
        options={{
          tabBarVisible: false,
          tabBarLabel: 'Message'
        }}
      />
      <Tab.Screen
        name="anotherTab"
        component={AnotherTabComponentExample}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'AnotherTab'
        }}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

more: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hiding-tabbar-in-screens/

Comment: this does not work for me

Comment: make sure you used react navigation version 5. 
if you used version 6 / above, the way to this is different..

Comment: I use version 5